# FacesContext isValidationFailed is returning false even when string to numeric conversion is failed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have form with so many values and each has its own validation. For simplicity I am taking only integer and string here.

```
<form jsf:id="aaaa" >
     <input type="text"
               jsf:id="number-field" 
               jsf:value="#{managedBean.bean.value1}"
               jsf:converterMessage="Error Integer"                           
      </input>
      <input type="text"
               jsf:id="text-field" 
               jsf:value="#{managedBean.bean.value2}"
               jsf:converterMessage="Error Text"                           
      </input>
      <button jsf:id="reset-data-button" 
                jsf:action="#{managedBean.save}" jsf:immediate="true">
                submit
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form/>
      </button>
</form>
```

The value1 is integer and value2 is string.

In my bean I am validating the fields manually and storing to database. I do not want to present error messages multiple times so I added immediate true.

In My bean

```
public void save() {                
    if (value1.valid() && value2.valid() && facesContext.isValidationFailed()) {
        //do some action
    }
}
```

Though `I have entered string value in value1 which is integer field` I get `facesContext.isValidationFailed() as false` but which should be true.

Am I doing any error here.

I am using mojarra 2.2.8

Comment: @kolossus yes I mean bean.value1 is of type integer. Can you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate attribute on the command button means that `action="#{managedBean.save}"` is executed immediately after the `APPLY_REQUEST` values phase. The problem this creates is that `value1` and `value2` will not have been set to the form entries at that time, so any logic depending on that condition will fail.

What you should have here is to mark those input components as `immediate="true"` and add a proper validator to the components. This combination will ensure that the components are validated at the same step as the `save` method is being executed. You still won't have access to the validated input values however; that doesn't happen until the `UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES` phase of the request processing, long after the `save` method has been executed

Comment: Thanks. Here my intention is to always call save method and do some business functionality though input field is invalid and save only when they are valid by type and by custom logic. Could you suggest me how to do that

Comment: You can do that in a view-based event handler like the `f:viewAction` since you're on JSF-2.2 @Patan

Comment: Wow, that comment and *"I do not want to present error messages multiple times so I added immediate true."* from the question indicates a big [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), Patan. I think it's wise to take a step back and clearly specify the concrete functional requirement, so that the right solution can be found.

Comment: @BalusC. Sorry for the confusion. I will ask new question with clear requirement.